# Basic C++ dynamic allocation issue

Tags: c++, dynamic

There is some basic facet of this that I'm completely missing. I have an object containing a set

```
PropertyContainer::PropertyContainer(string comFile, string resFile)
{
   set<Property*>* prCont = new set<Property*>();
...
}
```

In my main I'm calling

```
PropertyContainer* ptrPropertySet = new PropertyContainer(comFile, resFile);
```

This constructor goes through and populates the set with the data from the files.

If (while i'm still in the constructor) I iterate through the set all the Properties are there.

If I go back to main() and access the set it is empty (I've done it both through an accessor function and temporarily made it public and accessed it directly, to confirm i hadn't made a mistake in the accessor function)

This leads me to believe there is a very basic tenet of programming I'm missing. Any help or links would be appreciated.

Comment: You're defining a local variable `prCont`, which hides your member variable. It's very rare to dynamically allocate `std::set`s, and you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Why do you need all those pointers? Why does `prCont` has to be a pointer?

Comment: *facepalm* thank you so much @molbdnilo please make this an answer so i can choose it as the correct one :)

Comment: @ marius, prCont was a pointer to allow the call to new, which it turns out isn't necessary as molbdnilo pointed out and Property* is for polymorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining a local variable prCont, which hides your member variable.

It's very rare to dynamically allocate std::sets, and you probably shouldn't.
If you declare the member as `set<Property*> prCont`, it will be default-constructed automatically when your `PropertyContainer` is created.